# React Redux TypeError - is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to use `React` and `Redux` together to manage my app state.  I am trying to call a method off of my actions (`SprintActions`) , but I keep getting the error

`TypeError: props.getAllSprints is not a function`

Can you please let me know what am I doing wrong here ?

My main component is `Sprint` component and it imports `SprintActions`

This is my `Sprint` component.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { getSprints } from "./sprintActions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

export const Sprint = (props) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        props.getAllSprints();
    }, []);


    return (
        <div style={{ zIndex: 1 }}>
            {sprints &&
                sprints.map((s) => (
                <p>{s.id}</p>
                ))}

        </div>
    );
};
Sprint.propTypes = {
    getAllSprints: PropTypes.func,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    sprints: state.sprints,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    getAllSprints: bindActionCreators(getSprints, dispatch),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Sprint);
```

This is my `SprintActions`

```
import * as types from "../constants/ActionTypes";
import Axios from "axios";

export const getSprints = () => {
    console.log("get sprints");
    return (dispatch) => {
        Axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/sprints").then((response) => {
            const sprintData = response.data;
            dispatch(getAllSprints(sprintData));
        });
    };
};

export const getAllSprints = (data) => ({
    type: types.GET_SPRINTS,
    data: data,
});
```

Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: You have defined `getAllSprints` in `SprintActions` and you have also declared the same in `bindActionCreators`. 
Is that correct?
I think some naming mismatch is happening.

Comment: Is this correct? `import { getSprints } from "./sprintActions";` Shouldn't it be `import { getSprints } from "./SprintActions";`

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve here should be done either by using `redux-thunk`(to dispatch an api request) or `redux-sagas`(a little bit more complicated imo).
You can read [this guide](https://dev.to/markusclaus/fetching-data-from-an-api-using-reactredux-55ao) which is very helpful!

Your problem is that your `getSprints` action does not return an object with properties (type, ...payload) as [described here](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions). If you use your getAllSprints action instead you'll see that it will work.

Also check [the docs of redux for bindActionCreators](https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators)

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`bindActionCreators` is used for passing dispatch functionality into components that are not aware to your store, because you are anyhow using `mapDispatchToProps` inside `connect` there just no need for it (anyhow the way you implement it is bit wrong, welcome to look on https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators for doc).

Just make your mapDispatch as basic as possible:

---

```
  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
     getAllSprints: () => dispatch(getSprints()),
  });
```

---

#
**Edit**

you might add checker to your `useEffect` that `getAllSprint` is function (and this line executed after Redux context set), and a `[ props[getAllSprint] ]` dependency to run the effect again in case not

---

```
 useEffect(() =>
        typeof props[getAllSprint] == 'function' && props.getAllSprint()
       , [ props[getAllSprint] ])
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I am still getting the same reply. Please excuse me for the late reply.

Comment: Excuse me for the late reply as well, and in case you still face this issue I editing my answer

Answer (score 0):

In case you have multiple actions and you want to bind them all you can just do as follows

```
import * as sprintActions from "./sprintActions";

export const Sprint = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        props.sprintActions.getSprints();
    }, []);
    ...
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    sprintActions: bindActionCreators(sprintActions, dispatch),
});
```

Otherwise, you will need to manually call dispatch as suggested in other answers:

```
export const Sprint = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        props.getAllSprints();
    }, []);
    ...
};

 const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
     getAllSprints: () => dispatch(getSprints()),
 });
```

Comment: I am sorry , I chose the second option, but I am getting the same result. Sorry for the late reply.